# writing a query in which the date range is dependent on another field's value

Tags: t-sql

I am writing a report that has as part of the select clause will list a date (salesdate).  Salesdate is also used in the where clause to set the earliest sales date that the report is based on (for instance, I want the report to list all sales with a salesdate > 2012-11-01).  However, this date will change depending on another field in the report.  An example would be that for item = item1, I don't want any records earlier than 2012-10-01, but for item = item2, I don't want any records earlier than 2012-11-01.  I thought of this:

case when item = item1 then salesdate > 2012-10-01 else case when item = item2 then salesdate > 2012-11-01 in both the select and where clauses with not much confidence, and of course it didn't work (case not expecting a condition).  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: `salesdate > case item when item1 then cast ('20121001' as datetime) when item2 then cast ('20121101' as datetime) end`.

Comment: Thank you, Nikola!  This works perfectly well!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you could accomplish this with compound predicates in the WHERE clause.

For example:

```
...    WHERE (Item = Item1 AND SalesDate > '2012-10-01') OR (Item = Item2 AND SalesDate > '2012-11-01')
```

This will actually provide better performance because the SQL optimizer won't have to sort out the case statement within the WHERE clause.

HTH